# tomcat realm with database logins

Tags: tomcat9

Summary:

How would you validate a tomcat user providing the database(!) login credentials?

Details:

One thing I don't understand with tomcat is the realm config in combination with a relational database. It is clear what the JDBCRealm implementation does: Login to the database with a technical user, read the *users* table to find the login/password combination and these are the allowed logins. So the database has one technical user and a table.

But for a pure database frontend, the login should be validated by the database login mechanisms. In other words, the user provides the database username/password, then a new jdbc connection with this provided information is created and if successful, the provided login data is obviously correct. No technical database user, no table with a list of users.

Before I write that from scratch, is there something I overlooked? Does such a thing exist already?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Of course there are many cases where the database is just used as a directory of data. In my case I use the tomcat as frontend for a database application, with database users, database row level security, database permissions, database stored procedures, database...everything.

PPS: The follow up question will be connection pooling per-user. I have seen some hints on how to do that but any early input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions still but a REALM it is:

```
public class DBRealm extends RealmBase {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DBRealm.class);
    private String DBjdbcurl;
    private Map<String, DBPrincipal> userdirectory = new HashMap<>();

    public DBRealm() {
    }



    @Override
    public DBPrincipal authenticate(String username, String credentials) {
        log.info("Authenticating user \"" + username + 
                 "\" with database \"" + DBjdbcurl + "\"");
        try {
            DBPrincipal principal = new DBPrincipal(username, credentials, DBjdbcurl);
            // this does throw a SQLException in case the login data is invalid
            userdirectory.put(username, principal);
            return principal;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("failed to login with the provided credentials for \"" + 
                      username + "\" with database \"" + DBjdbcurl + 
                      "\" and exception " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPassword(String username) {
        return null; 
        // Do not expose the password. What is the side effect of that with md5 digest???
    }

    @Override
    protected DBPrincipal getPrincipal(String username) {
        return userdirectory.get(username);
    }

    /*
     * Properties
     */

    public String getDBJDBCURL() {
        return DBjdbcurl;
    }

    public void setDBJDBCURL(String DBjdbcurl) {
        this.DBjdbcurl = DBjdbcurl;
    }
}
```